# Core Data Duplicate Object Handeling

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, duplicates

I have an application which allows users to create documents with a title and assign an author to it.  I am trying to prevent duplicate objects from being entered into my core data database when new objects are imported from a list.  I am trying to follow the suggestions in [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html), which suggests loading all the objects being imported, then query the database to see if any of those objects already exist, then handle the duplicates appropriately.  In their example they are querying off of a single attribute:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(employeeID IN %@)", employeeIDs]];
```

In my case, though, I have two attributes which define a unique object: title, and author. So I cant simply use:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(title IN %@) AND (author IN %@)", titleList, authorList]];
```

I know I could use a series of or statements, but that seems inefficient.

Any ideas of how to efficiently get just the objects with the correct title-author pairing?

Comment: Technically, in the database I have an authors entity and a document entity.  The list of authors is unique, but I am trying to ensure that their titles of there documents is also unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need 2 Entities. Document and Author. Document has a title property and relationship to Author. Then on importing, it would need to be 2 stages, but that's not so bad.

First you could import all the new Authors, first checking the authors that already exist.

Then process the new Documents, excluding the documents that already exist and creating a relationship with the Author.

I don't think you need to try and get any more clever than this for this situation - you will just complicate it.

Comment: Currently I do have two entities, one for the author and one for the document.  However, the problem still remains on how to know if a document exists for a particular author.  I suppose I could verify the poems author by author, but I was hoping to do it all in one single query.  I did think of perhaps creating another (transient) attribute of the author name and the document title.  Then I could query against that attribute.

Comment: Seems like more of an SQL problem first. Figuring out how to retrieve that data, then how to apply that SQL in the context of core data. Ask it in an SQL forum first and then bring the result back here.